# Angular/Mobile App Shoping Cart Prices Storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

Hi I have a question about prices storage in mobile/angular apps connecting to some API by token based auth. In example fronend Angular connect to Symfony2 API by Oauth2. On standard web app when I add something to shopping cart the price is saved in session data on server side so when I continue to checkout and in meanwhile price changes I will buy for that price I aded item to cart. So what about Angular or mobile apps that connect by token based, and do not have any info on server side ? Storing prices in local stroage, seems bad for me ?

Comment: If you can save something like an id for the item and fetch it at checkout, that'd be good.

Comment: Yes but my question is what when meanwhile price changes it is a good practice to sell by the price that user add something to cart not else price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In general, you don't want to store anything on the client side, that has to do with controlling the server-based transaction (such as price), otherwise, somebody may reverse-engineer your product and start buying items for "luckily stored" 1 USD.

2) What stops you from using the same mechanism in your mobile app as you are using with standard web-app.

Comment: I question because I want to make API in Symfony and Angular Client App, the client app I want to be able to connect by Oauth2, but than I have not Session on the Server side (only access token connected to user in database), so I can't do this standard way I think.

Comment: Ah ok. I see. in this case,  you have to store not only the user information by this access token, but also "session information". Essentially, by using different APIs on your server with given access token you should be able to access data in a correct state. For example, once you select a product to buy, its information is stored in the database as reserved product for given access token. Later you can find this information when you commit to the transaction.

Comment: Yes I think about that but I wonder if there is some better solutions, this what you wrote is good of course but I have to store information and I think manage deleting old sessions, when user close app or something like that. I was curious how it can be manage other ways. But if there are no other solutions ,thanks for consultations :)

Comment: For deleting the old sessions you have to do the following: 1) allow user to logout (and remove data on logout). 2) delete sessions for which tokens have expired. 3) once same user is logging in again, remove old sessions. As a bonus, if your application stores the session key locally, then user may continue the old session even if page reloads.